# Using percentage function with accumarray

Tags: arrays, matlab, percentage, accumarray

I have two arrays:

```
OTPCORorder = [61,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,65,65,...]
AprefCOR = [1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,2,...]
```

for each element in OTPCORorder there is a corresponding element in AprefCOR.
I want to know the percent of the number 1 for each set of unique OTPCORorder as follows:

```
OTPCORorder1 = [61,62,65,...]
AprefCOR1 = [1,0.72,0,...]
```

I already have this:

```
[OTPCORorder1,~,idx] = unique(OTPCORorder,'stable');
ANS = OTPCORorder1 = [61,62,65,...];
```

and I used to work with "accumarray" but I used the "mean" or "sum" function such as this:

```
AprefCOR1 = accumarray(idx,AprefCOR,[],@mean).';
```

I was just wondering if there exists a way to use this but with "prctile" function or any other function that gives me the percent of a specific element for example "1" in this case.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be one approach:

```
%// make all those non-zero values to zero
AprefCORmask = AprefCOR == 1;

%// you have done this
[OTPCORorder1,~,idx] = unique(OTPCORorder,'stable');

%// Find number of each unique values
counts = accumarray(idx,1);

%// Find number of ones for each unique value
sumVal = accumarray(idx,AprefCORmask);

%// find percentage of ones to get the results
perc = sumVal./counts
```

**Results:**

**Inputs:**

```
OTPCORorder = [61,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,65,65];
AprefCOR = [1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,2];
```

**Output:**

```
perc =

1.0000
0.7273
     0
```

Comment: @chinkare_16 you are welcome. BTW, When you have time accept any one of our answers which ever you feel better satisfied your problem

Comment: @SanthanSalai - Because the OP wanted an approach via `accumarray`, the answer to accept should be yours as you did what the OP requested.  I provided an alternative because `accumarray` in this case (at least in my opinion) would be slower.

Comment: @SanthanSalai and now you are a 3k user... Congrats :-)

Comment: I accidentally down voted. In order to change my vote, I had to edit your post. It won't let you change your vote once a certain grace period elapses. Forgot to upvote it too!

Answer (score 4):

Here's another approach without using `accumarray`.  I think it's more readable:

```
>> list = unique(PCORorder);
>> counts_master = histc(PCORorder, list);
>> counts = histc(PCORorder(AprefCOR == 1), list);
>> perc = counts ./ counts_master

perc =

    1.0000    0.7273         0
```

How the above code works is that we first find those elements in `PCORorder` that are unique.  Once we do this, we first count up how many elements belong to each unique value in `PCORorder` via [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) using the bins to count at as this exact list.  If you're using a more newer version of MATLAB, use [`histcounts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html) instead... same syntax.  Once we find the total number of elements for each value in `PCORorder`, we simply count up how many elements correspond to `PCORorder` where `AprefCOR == 1` and then to calculate the percentage, you simply divide each entry in this list with the total number of elements from the previous list.

It'll give you the same results as `accumarray` but with less overhead.

Comment: Without accumarray is good :) Our logic ended similar though :) +1

Comment: Thanks :) `accumarray` is great but if you seriously just want to use it to tally up values in 1D, `histc` is actually faster.

Comment: Yeah i agree. :) Still learning from you guys to make things efficient :D

Comment: @SanthanSalai - heh :) TBH, last year I was in exactly the same shoes you were.  I was starting to write answers here... and I started learning things from Luis Mendo, Divakar, Amro, etc.... I would usually write answers, then those guys would suggest something that made my code look terrible lol.   I admire you for beginning to write answers and I'm starting to see the maturity in the way you're writing them... from answers that didn't use much of MATLAB's functions to using more of them and having answers with less code.  You've made great progress.  Keep it up!

Comment: Thats a great compliment hearing from you :) Full credits to you guys. Still a kid in matlab though (<4 months experience). Although i'm using my Vacation as much as possible learning MatLab here from you guys, sadly the vacation is about to get over. Will not be this active anymore. Thanks again for all the help :)

Comment: A while back I did some benchmarks for my own personal interest on this `@mean` finding against other alternatives, but never presented them here. I might do it soon though.

Comment: @SanthanSalai I agree with rayryeng. You're making great progress! Keep it up!

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks. That means a lot to me :)

Comment: @SanthanSalai So it's the holiday? I thought everyone was making vast progress because they were up at 4am, like rayryeng :-)

Comment: @kkuilla yes you are right. It was 3 months summer vacation for me and its about to get over :( you know his timezone? It may not be 4am for him :P

Comment: It was 4 am :P. I live in Toronto Canada.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach works, you only need to define an  appropriate [anonymous function](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) to be used by [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html). Let `value = 1` be the value whose percentage you want to compute. Then

```
[~, ~, u] = unique(OTPCORorder); %// labels for unique values in OTPCORorder
result = accumarray(u(:), AprefCOR(:), [], @(x) mean(x==value)).';
```

---

As an alternative, you can use [`sparse`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) as follows. Generate a two-row matrix sucha that each column corresponds to one of the possible values in `OTPCORorder`. First row tallies how many times each value in `OTPCORorder` had the desired value in `AprefCOR`; second row tallies how many times it didn't.

```
[~, ~, u] = unique(OTPCORorder);
s = full(sparse((AprefCOR==value)+1, u, 1));
result = s(2,:)./sum(s,1);
```